# php strtotime array sorting issue

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, yii

I'd like to start off by saying thank you for taking the time to read this post. I hope that someone will be kind enough to help me as I am just starting to learn PHP. Please forgive me if I do not use the correct terminology to describe my issue.

I'm having an issue sorting my array.

My array looks like this:

```
<?php
$rooms = array(
  strtotime('next monday')=>array('day'=>'monday', 'abbrev'=>'Mon'),
  strtotime('next tuesday')=>array('day'=>'tuesday', 'abbrev'=>'Tue'),
  strtotime('next wednesday')=>array('day'=>'wednesday', 'abbrev'=>'Wed'),
  strtotime('next thursday')=>array('day'=>'thursday', 'abbrev'=>'Thu'),
  strtotime('next friday')=>array('day'=>'friday', 'abbrev'=>'Fri'),
  strtotime('next saturday')=>array('day'=>'saturday', 'abbrev'=>'Sat'),
  strtotime('next sunday')=>array('day'=>'sunday', 'abbrev'=>'Sun'));
ksort($rooms);

foreach($rooms as $room_timestamp=>$room_info) {
  if (time() > strtotime($room_info['day'])) {
  print ($form->checkBox($model,'space_'.$room_info['day'], array('value' => strtotime($room_info['day']))) . $form->labelEx($model,$room_info['abbrev'].' ' . date('n/j', strtotime($room_info['day']))) . '<br />');
  } else {
  print ($form->checkBox($model,'space_'.$room_info['day'], array('value' => strtotime('next '.$room_info['day']))) . $form->labelEx($model,$room_info['abbrev'].' ' . date('n/j', strtotime('next '.$room_info['day']))) . '<br />');
  }
}

echo "<pre>".print_r($rooms,1)."</pre>";
?>
```

And it is outputting the checkboxes in this order:

Mon 6/3
Tue 6/4
Wed 6/5
Thu 6/6
Fri 6/7
Sat 6/8
Sun 6/2

I'm trying to get today (in this case Sun 6/2) to show first, and then the next 6 days to show in order.

When I use print_r to display the raw output, it looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [1370239200] => Array
        (
            [day] => monday
            [abbrev] => Mon
        )

    [1370325600] => Array
        (
            [day] => tuesday
            [abbrev] => Tue
        )

    [1370412000] => Array
        (
            [day] => wednesday
            [abbrev] => Wed
        )

    [1370498400] => Array
        (
            [day] => thursday
            [abbrev] => Thu
        )

    [1370584800] => Array
        (
            [day] => friday
            [abbrev] => Fri
        )

    [1370671200] => Array
        (
            [day] => saturday
            [abbrev] => Sat
        )

    [1370757600] => Array
        (
            [day] => sunday
            [abbrev] => Sun
        )

)
```

Sunday is showing a larger time stamp than the other days, is this because it is somehow outputting next Sunday's time stamp instead of today's time stamp?

Initially I was creating the checkboxes and labels using two if/else statements for each day. Unable to sort them this way I attempted to create an array which is what I am now having trouble with.

My original code (this example is for Tuesday) looked like this:

```
            <?php
        if (time() > strtotime('tuesday'))
        {
            echo $form->checkBox($model,'space_tuesday', array('value' => strtotime('tuesday'))); 
        }
        else
        {
            echo $form->checkBox($model,'space_tuesday', array('value' => strtotime('next tuesday'))); 
        }

         ?>
        <?php 
        if (time() > strtotime('tuesday'))
        {
            echo $form->labelEx($model,'Tues ' . date('n/j', strtotime('tuesday'))); 
        }
        else
        {
            echo $form->labelEx($model,'Tues ' . date('n/j', strtotime('next tuesday'))); 
        }
        ?>
```

Is there a better way to create an array to achieve this and sort in the correct order? Am I missing something simple with the array I've already created?

Any help that you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand it, for what you want to achieve, you're overcomplicating things:

```
for ( $i=0; $i<6; $i++ ) {
  echo date('D n/j', strtotime("+$i day")) . '<br />';
}
```

Days naturally progress in the way you want, so you might as well use that fact — and avoid sorting all together. You can also make use of php's date formatting to avoid having to store shortforms of days too.

#### update

This should give you an idea of what you can do, I'd suggest you read up on what you can generate using PHP's date function — it's rather useful :)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
for ( $i=0; $i<6; $i++ ) {
  /// pull out our datetime into a variable
  $datetime = strtotime("+$i day");
  /// wrap it with an array ready for checkBox()
  $value = array('value' => $datetime);
  /// generate the different parts we may need from date()
  list($day, $formatted) = explode(',', date('l,D n/j', $datetime));
  /// place those parts where we need them
  echo $form->checkBox($model, "space_" . strtolower($day), $value);
  echo $form->labelEx($model, $formatted));
}
```

Comment: pebbl, thank you very much. I'm having some trouble utilizing the wisdom you have bestowed upon me. The part I don't understand is how I would work your solution into my checkbox statement. echo $form->checkBox($model,'space_tuesday', array('value' => strtotime('+$i day'))); -- how would I get it to add the correct day name to space_dayname. I have a similar issue trying to get it to work for my label statement, where I'm using: echo $form->labelEx($model,'Tues ' . date('n/j', strtotime('+$i day')));

Comment: pebbl, I cannot thank you enough. I will definitely read up on the php date function, I'm just beginning to learn PHP as I've always been a front end developer until recently. If you're ever in the Boston area I'd love to buy you a pint! cheers!

Comment: @AntiHero Ah, no worries, glad it helped :) `php.net` is definitely your friend when it comes to php! Good luck with learning server side.

Answer (score 0):

Change 'next sunday' to 'sunday', put it in as the first array element and you should be good..

Answer (score 0):

> Sunday is showing a larger time stamp than the other days, is this because it is somehow outputting next Sunday's time stamp instead of today's time stamp?

Yes, this is what you coded: `strtotime('next sunday')`

Try using numbers if you want today and next 6 days, e.g.+1 day, ..., +6 days: http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php